# Symfony2 - DoctrineMongoDBBundle - Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to use the DoctrineMongoDBBundle, however, i'm running into an issue.

In my config.yml, I have:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options:
                connect: true
    default_database: symfony2
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

My User.php class:

```
<?php
namespace HALL\HelloWorldBundle\Document;
use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /** @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto") */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

When I run the command:

```
 php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents HALLHelloWorldBundle
```

I get the following error:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>   [Semantical Error] The annotation
>   "@Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Document" in class
>   HALL\HelloWorldBundle\Document\User does not exist, or could not be
>   auto-loaded.

Any ideas why? The annotation is clearly referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registering the annotations as in Jamie's solution did not work for me. It solved this problem but meant that the annotations object could not be unserialized from the cache . Registering the annotations like this:

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/Annotations/DoctrineAnnotations.php');
```

Meant that the original issue was resolved without introducing the issue relating to the cache.

Comment: In the end I used `require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/Annotations/DoctrineAnnotations.php';
Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();
` However, yours seems like a better solution! Accepted yours at the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Solution found.

http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2/browse_thread/thread/0d45a6bfe4b04ee7/645f347c77bdc3e6?show_docid=645f347c77bdc3e6

in app/autoload.php, I needed to add:

```
Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();
```

Ah, I wish the documentation would tell me this....

Comment: Then edit the doc and make a pull request (and SAVE THE WORLD) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should register the annotation classes on bootstrap, this can be done in 2 ways. Using the static call as detailed by Richard. Or...

You can use the registerAnnotationClasses() method on your driver object. This should do exactly the same thing but doesn't require a path parameter (as it should have already been given when setting up your driver on bootstrap).

```
use \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Configuration;

.........

$configuration = new Configuration();
$driver = $configuration->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($path_to_docs);
$driver->registerAnnotationClasses();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution found in [Documentation of DoctrineMongoDBBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#register-the-annotations-and-the-bundle)

your app/autoload.php must be like this :

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver; <-- add this line 

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();  <-- add this line

return $loader;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

In the doc you can find this part of configuration